# TestFlight Invalid IPA: Must specify MinimumOSVersion

Tags: xcode, distribution, adhoc, ipa, testflight

I have idea what happened recently with TestFlight. I have been uploading hundreds of bundles using TestFlight App and Xcode Archives.

With my recen target I get this and i have no idea where does it come from. I do everything the same as with my other apps:

1. Archive target with signing it with my AdHos certificate / provisioning profile
2. Go to Organizer / Archivers / open in Finder and drop archive to the TestFlight app
3. TestFlight app builds IPA and uploads but this time it ends with the same error:

[image]

As you can see even on screenshot, I have deployment target specified (minimum). I have also tried to specify minimum ios version in info file as instructed here (even if I believe I shouldn't do it in Info.plist):
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/150078/invalid-ipa-must-specify-minimumosversiontestfligh
[image]

But it did not help.

Comment: I was always just dragging and dropping .xcarchive and testFlight used to take care of the rest. Why should it be diffrent this time? Specially when Ijust tried the same with another target from that project (let's say - Life version) and it always worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my Info.plist was included in the "Copy Bundle Resoures" build phase list. 
I had to prevent it to be copied to the  target. 
It can also be done by clicking on this file and remove if from "Target Membership" in the file properties panel.
After removing in from target destination - everything went back to normal.

Comment: I have no Plist in Copy Bundle Resources and still get this error. Any other ideas?